# Is empirical reliability in IRT the counterpart of internal consistency in CTT?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, item-response-theory

In IRT it is not meaningful to compute internal consistency coefficients such as Cronbachs alpha, because standard error of measurement (and thus measurement precision) is not assumed uniform across the latent trait continuum.

In order to estimate reliability based on one test administration in IRT, there is an alternative, simulation-based approach, often referred to as [empirical reliability](https://books.google.de/books?id=fbH0RgiZmoAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=du+toit+IRT+from+SSI:+BILOG-MG,+MULTILOG,+PARSCALE,+TESTFACT&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAGoVChMIyqWjtOGPyAIV62tyCh1ZrA2W#v=onepage&q=empirical%20reliability&f=false).

My question now is:

Is it ok to say that empirical reliability in IRT is the equivalent of internal consistency in CTT?

If it is, *why* is it ok? If it is not, why not? What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent, certainly not. Approximately equal I think would be a better statement. Both are empirical estimates of the (marginal) reliability, and simply go about the issue differently when decomposing true score and error variance.

Coefficient $\alpha$ uses the total score composite term as the basis for the computations (making a subtle $\tau$-equivalence assumption) while the IRT approach uses the trait estimates and their associated standard errors as the composite terms. Of course, that's what makes the IRT approach slightly less universal because there are different ways to obtain $\hat{\theta}$. Which prediction method should you use? ML, EAP, WLE, EAP for sum scores, etc.